# Issue in using "New Build System (Preview)" new feature Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: xcode9

In Xcode 9 “**New Build System (Preview)**” option in **Build setting** (as in the image shown below) has been introduced and it is used for improving build times for the projects as stated in the WWDC session(https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/)

[image]
[image]

It works fine for new projects which I created in Xcode 9 recently.
But it doesn’t work for my older projects(big ones), And I found the following similar kind of issue log for most of the projects

> error: unable to build node:
>   '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECTNAME.app/Info.plist'
>   (node is produced by multiple commands; e.g.,
>   ‘313423sfkjsahdfkashdfklahsdlfkjhsalkfjhh33123sfas:CopyPlistFile
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME-hgfopfsnfsimmzcupjfdhkomofte/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECTNAME.app/Info.plist
>   /Users/admin/Projects/Official/PROJECTNAME-ios-2100bd9ec02e/PROJECTNAME/SupportingFiles/Info.plist'
>   and
>   '313423sfkjsahdfkashdfklahsdlfkjhsalkfjhh33123sfas:ProcessInfoPlistFile
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME-hgfopfsnfsimmzcupjfdhkomofte/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECTNAME.app/Info.plist
>   /Users/admin/Projects/Official/PROJECTNAME-ios-2100bd9ec02e/PROJECTNAME/SupportingFiles/Info.plist')

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you try to delete the Derived Data folder?

Comment: @the4kman: Yes I did. But no luck

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem, search for .plist files in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase, there shouldn't be any plist file there, in my case this was preventing the new build system to build.

Comment: I had to do this in one of my `cocoapod` targets. Resolved the issue in my case!

Comment: I remove all .plist files in "Copy Bundle Resource" phase and it works. Can you explain it?

Comment: I guess the new build system doesn't work with files copied multiple times in the bundle, I think it should be a warning as with the old build system. As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1649/_index.html) , the info.plist linked to the active target in implicitly added to it, so, you don't need to add it to your target.

Comment: @PeterSchaeffer: It worked great, Thank you. And in my case, I had to do the same in all my targets(iOS app, Watch app & Widget) to make the project build.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is solved, but mine was a different cause. I had two 3rd party SDKs that had simple text files with the same name (LICENSE). This was probably just a warning in the old build system.

I just removed one of the files from the target and everything works again.